# Word Search solving algorithm

Tags: java, optimization

The following is my wordsearch solving algorithm. I'd greatly appreciate tips on how to improve it (e.g. improve efficiency, better approach, etc.):

```
public boolean traverse(Grid grid) {
    for (int r = 0; r < grid.getRows(); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < grid.getCols(); c++) {
            for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
                currentPoint.y = r;
                currentPoint.x = c;
                this.direction = direction;

                if (find(grid, currentPoint, 0)) {
                    for (Point point : consideredPoints) {
                        grid.markLetterAt(point);
                    }

                   return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

`Direction` is an enum with all the cardinal directions (N, NE, S, NW, etc...). It has a method (`updatePoint()`) which changes a `Point` to the direction (e.g. NE does `point.y -= 1`, `point.x += 1`)

Here is `find`:

```
private boolean find(Grid grid, Point point, int count) {
    if (!grid.isValidLetter(point)) { // Checks if the point is valid (e.g not < 0)
        consideredPoints.clear();
        return false;
    }

    if (grid.getLetterAt(point).equals(word.substring(count, count + 1))) {
        consideredPoints.add(new Point(point));

        if (count == word.length() - 1) {
            return true;
        }

        direction.updatePoint(point);
        return find(grid, point, count + 1);
    }

    consideredPoints.clear();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You are creating lots of Point() objects. For performance optimization in Java the very first thing is to avoid pressure on the garbage collector.
- You are doing lots of repeated calculations just for traversing the grid (in several directions). Performance wise it would be much better to *transform the whole grid* in advance to simplify the traversal calculation. E.g. it is very simple to search only words in East direction in a grid. And searching words in West direction could then be done by mirroring the grid against a vertical axis and searching again in East direction only.
- For just finding words, you can ignore the grid structure entirely. Take the complete first row as String, append a space, append the complete second row as String and so forth. You get one huge string representing the grid for searching in East direction. Your matching code is simply `hugeString.contains(searchWord)` (with a bit more complicated calculation of the original row and column information). You can do the same transformation from grid to a single String also for all other directions.